# compare multidimensional array to multidimensional array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays I'd like to extract the matches from and return them. The first array is my query array of sorts, The second would be the database of sorts if you would like to call it that. With that in mind, being rusty as I am with PHP I am trying to figure out how I can loop over these with as little overhead as possible while returning only unique matching whole objects from the second. Is there a clean method of doing this with php? If so could anyone help point me in the general direction.

**First:**

```
[
   ["something", "domain.com"],
   ["something1", "sub.domain.com"]
]
```

**Second:**

```
[
{
   "id": "abcde12345",
   "name": "Company Name",
   "corp_name": [
     "Company, Inc.",
     "Company Inc."
   ],
   "_names": [],
   "_products": [],
   "urls": [
      "www.domain.com",
      "domain.com",
      "sub.domain.com"
   ]
},
{
   "id": "abcde12345",
   "name": "Company Name",
   "corp_name": [
     "Company, Inc.",
     "Company Inc."
   ],
   "_names": [],
   "_products": [],
   "urls": [
      "www.domain.com",
      "domain.com",
      "sub.domain.com"
   ]
}.
{
   "id": "abcde12345",
   "name": "Company Name",
   "corp_name": [
     "Company, Inc.",
     "Company Inc."
   ],
   "_names": [],
   "_products": [],
   "urls": [
      "www.domain.com",
      "domain.com",
      "sub.domain.com"
   ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function to compare arrays

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

in the comments bellow, there's a recursive version. I allowed myself to paste a copy here.

```
<?php
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2) {
    $difference=array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            if( !isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key]) ) {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if( !empty($new_diff) )
                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        } else if( !array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value ) {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $difference;
}
?>
```

Comment: note: JSON objects are mapped to arrays in PHP. So to use this function, use json_decode($json, true) to get an array instead of StdClass